# Is it possible to link or "redirect" to an App in Windows RT?

Tags: .net, windows-runtime

On the IOS platform, it's possible to give a browser a link to an app on the device, such that following the link causes the app to launch and handle the request. E.g.:

```
 pownce://foo/etc
```

Is there any similar approach in writing WinRT apps? This would be very significant in handling federated identity and authentication flows that make heavy use of browser redirects to relay information between parties.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/497213/1503

Comment: From the answer in that question, I see it's possible, but I need to know more details about how you might go about setting this up, specifically choosing the value of the "name".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Windows Store apps can be set up to handle protocol activation, which is described in the app manifest. (This will set up the necessary registry entries at installation time--you can't do that manually for an app distributed via the Windows Store.) It basically allows for the same thing: define your own URI scheme and register an app as a handler for that scheme.

See [How to Handle Protocol Activation (HTML/JS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452686.aspx) or the [equivalent topic for C#/VB/XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh779670%28v=win.10%29.aspx).

Comment: As a note, [taglines and signatures are strongly discouraged in answers here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5038/135615), particularly ones that promote products (even free ones) by the author.